# Siddhi CEP as library : Number of ExecutionPlan per SiddhiManager instance

Tags: siddhi

I am new to Siddhi CEP. We are planning to use it as a standalone java library. We planned to have one instance of SiddhiManager consuming different event streams with each event stream mapped to one execution plan with queries.

In the below mail thread there is mention to use one SiddhiManager instance per scenario.
http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/architecture/2014-March/015501.html

So is there any limit on the number of execution plans per Siddhi Manager instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit like that where as you can have multiple ExecutionPlanRuntimes per SiddhiManager. Please use latest Siddhi 3.0.0 which was released last month and refer [SiddhiQL 3.0.0 documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.0) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer by @Tharik, There is no hard limit set on the number of execution plans that can be created per Siddhi Manager instance.

The issue discussed in the mail thread above was mainly due to limitations in how events were distributed to multiple streams in Siddhi-2.x branch. This is fixed in Siddhi-3.x branch with a completely new architecture that inherently makes use of multiple threads more efficiently.

However, if you create a very large number(1000-10000) of execution plans within a single instance of SiddhiManager, a large number of threads will be created within the SiddhiManager which can lead to some performance degradation. This is will of course depend on your usecase and the type of queries you are running. This will have to be addressed by scaling your deployment according to your particular use case.